# Написание сниффера

Tags: сниффер

Здравствуйте, получил задание - это написать сниффер, посоветуйте что можно использовать, какие языки и т.д...
Сниффер должен уметь - просматривать какие есть компы в сети и видеть открытые порты.
Предпочтение таким языкам как Java, Python и Delphi.
Сниффер должен быть с графическим интерфейсом.

Comment: ну еще думаю что вот такие доп функции не помешали бы:

1. нужно получить список IP-адресов, которые принадлежат заданной подсети
2. нужно получить список IP-адресов компьютеров, которые сейчас работают в заданной подсети
3. нужно получить список IP-адресов компьютеров, на которых есть общие (с точки зрения Microsoft) ресурсы
4. нужно получить список IP-адресов компьютеров, на которых есть общие (с любой точки зрения) ресурсы

Answer (score 5):

Вряд ли сниффер можно отнести к тому, что у вас написано в комментарии, да и в вопросе тоже. Это скорее уже сканер портов.

Тем не менее как его не называй:

1. Список адресов. Что имеется ввиду? Если все возможные адреса, то элементарно берется адрес интерфейса, *на котором висит ваш снифер,* и маска сети. *Бинарной операцией `And` между IP и маской, вы получаете сеть. Широковещательный (broadcast) IP вы получите если возмете бинарное `Or` между вашим IP и инвертированной маской сети.*
2. Для определения работает компьютер можно самым простым методом воспользоваться - пинг (ping = ICMP Echo). *Реализуется просто, в гугле полно примеров для разных языков. В более сложном случае вы переходите к п.3/4*
3. Чтобы определить ресурсы Windows смотрите порты 137, 139, 445. *Но это не даст гарантии наличия открытых ресурсов. Для обнаружения самих ресурсов, придется как-то работать с протоколом обмена, видимо*
4. Другие ресурсы. Сканером портов проверяете порты *(все подряд или выборочно)*. Если порт открыт, по номеру порта, смотрите соответствие сервису. Обычно этого достаточно. Если же порты открыты другие, вместо тех, что определены по-умолчанию для сервисов, анализируете по типу протокола. Но в данном случае придется много думать, много искать и много работать.

В общих чертах я описал суть решения вашей задачи. Примеров достаточно в интернете, идеи разжованы.

Хотелось бы отметить, что основная задача снифера - отлов пакетов, которые видит интерфейс. Реализовать это можно и в Java, и в С++, и в C#. На последнем и сам пробовал с библиотекой libpcap.

Comment: ok,для Java в какую сторону капать?

Comment: google не пробовали? даже основные фразы для него я вам написал

Comment: Еще для поиска компьютеров можно с arp-ом поиграться. Заодно MAC адреса выясните. 

Вообще-то хороший сниффер (в дополнение к активному сканированию адресов/портов) переключает интерфейс в promiscuous mode и слушает все пакеты в сети. При подключении через switch пытается его "слегка ломануть", заставляя транслировать на свой порт все пакеты, проходящие через switch. 

@Azwart, этот комментарий тоже можете расценивать, как набор ключевых слов для поиска.

Comment: ок, все учту

Comment: @avp, ARP будет работать только, если предварительно опросить клиентов, хотя нельзя не отметить, что на его основе получится сделать неплохой сканер работающих компов.

Comment: Кстати, вместо "честного" ARP (броадсаст запрос, чтение ответов), можно воспользоваться системной ARP-таблицей, переложив всю работу с ARP протоколом на ОС. 

Перебираем локальные IP и делаем connect с произвольным портом. Если получаем отлуп то смотрим, а вообще такой IP в ARP-таблице появился?

Возможно это имеет смысл делать только с адресами, которые ранее не откликнулись на пинг.